URL inside an email template doesn't land on the given URL
I have a  tag inside our HTML email template which resembles a button. the Achor tag in my code looks like :
<a href="https://example.com">Click here to restore your password </a>.
But when someone clicks on the link inside the template it goes to "url9216.example.com" and they see a "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".
Is there a way for me to do something with the button so that it goes to example.com and not url9216.example.com.
I tried to do something like this:
<p> https://example.com</p>
And that works but when I add it to the anchor tag's href. It goes to url9216.example.com.

Are you using an email marketing platform ? they might be altering the links for tracking purposes.

Either remove the https:
<a href="example.com">Click here to ... </a>

Or:
let url = "https://example.com";

<a href="{{ url }}">Click here to ... </a>

